# ActiveRecord::QueryMethod 'includes' ignroes my select method. How do I approach this?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

So I'm having a little problem here.  Basically I have two tables - `restaurants` and `inspections` (`restaurant` model `has_many :inspections`.  I need to pull a list of restaurants that have been given a certain score on their inspections (in this case it's 70).  The idea is to get all the inspections for each restaurant.

If I run the following command in my console...

```
places = Restaurant.joins(:inspections).where("zip = '78741' AND score = 70").select("name, ST_AsGeoJSON(the_geom) as gj")
```

...I get a list of restaurants as expected.  It returns the name and a geojson geometry.  Perfect.  How do I know go about iterating over `places` without running into the whole 1 + N problem.  I tried using `includes` but that removes the ability to write my own `select` method.  Any thoughts?

From my models

```
InspectionModel
belongs_to :restaurant, foreign_key: :facility_id

RestaurantModel
has_many :inspections, foreign_key: :facility_id, primary_key: :facility_id
```

From my db:

```
psql (9.3.3)
Type "help" for help.

maple_dev=# \d+ inspections
                             Table "public.inspections"
   Column    |       Type        |   Modifiers  | Storage  | Stats target | Description 
-------------+-------------------+--------------+----------+--------------+-------------
 date        | date              |              | plain    |              | 
 score       | integer           |              | plain    |              | 
 facility_id | character varying |              | extended |              | 
 description | character varying |              | extended |              | 
 id          | integer           | not null ... | plain    |              | 
Indexes:
    "inspections_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "index_inspections_on_facility_id" btree (facility_id)
Has OIDs: no

maple_dev=# \d+ restaurants
                             Table "public.restaurants"
   Column    |       Type        | Modifiers | Storage  | Stats target | Description 
-------------+-------------------+-----------+----------+--------------+-------------
 facility_id | character varying |           | extended |              | 
 name        | character varying |           | extended |              | 
 zip         | character(5)      |           | extended |              | 
 address     | character varying |           | extended |              | 
 latitude    | double precision  |           | plain    |              | 
 longitude   | double precision  |           | plain    |              | 
 the_geom    | geometry          |           | main     |              | 
Indexes:
    "index_restaurants_on_facility_id" btree (facility_id)
Has OIDs: no
```

Comment: can you add the schema of both model.

Comment: I don't actually think `includes` would have an issue with this.  I ran a quick test and it worked fine.  What error do you get?

Comment: @ParitoshPiplewar updated. @steakchaser it doesnt work because `includes` doesnt allow a custom select (which I need here).  It works just fine but but does `SELECT *` rather than what I told it.

Comment: That's not what I see when I run a similar test.  The only diff between what we are doing is that you are calling a stored proc.

Comment: I'd like to see some output of that because every resource I've read on the matter says you cant and my experience shows that.  If it works for you I'd love to know how.

Comment: `Athlete.includes(:scans).where("athletes.id = 1").select("athletes.first_name")` produces `SELECT athletes.first_name FROM "athletes" WHERE (athletes.id = 1)`.  Pulling in fields from the `scans` table creates the normal monster query for the `includes` part of this.

Comment: `12.0.0-p353 :013 > Restaurant.includes(:inspections).where("restaurants.zip = '78741'").select("restaurants.name")
  Restaurant Load (1.4ms)  SELECT restaurants.name FROM "restaurants" WHERE (restaurants.zip = '78741')
(Object doesn't support #inspect)
 =>  
2.0.0-p353 :014 >`

Comment: I solved it with the `preload` method. Basically I do a join since I need both tables and then `.preload(:inspections)` and it works just fine.  Thanks for the assistance.

Comment: @Nick McD. You should answer the question yourself and mark it as the correct answer. This is encouraged when you work it out yourself.

Comment: My mistake. I'll get on it. Thanks @DonCruickshank.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ActiveRecord Association Extensions](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#association-extensions):

```
#app/models/restaurant.rb
Class Restaurant < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :inspections, foreign_key: :facility_id, primary_key: :facility_id do
       def score(zip, score)
           where("zip = ? AND score = ?", zip, score).select("name, ST_AsGeoJSON(the_geom) as gj")
       end
   end
end
```

This would allow you to call:

```
@location1 = Restaraunt.inspections.score("01456", "70")
@location2 = Restaraunt.inspections.score("15654", "80")
```

---

**Process**

1. Set "places" as variable data -- currently, it's manual
2. Use a method to call all required data to your specifications

AR Association Extensions are a little-known feature of Rails, and basically allow you to define specifics about the data you're calling. I don't know if my code will work out the box, but it will definitely point you in the right direction

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out that the combination of methods I needed was `joins` and `preload`.  As stated elsewhere, using `includes` defaults the `select` method to return all columns.  In my case I needed to run a PostGIS function in my `select` call and so `includes` wont work.  Below is the working code:

```
restaurant_info = Restaurant.joins(:inspections)
                            .preload(:inspections)
                            .select(atts)
                            .where("#{score_search} AND #{q_where}")
```

This actually didn't totally fix things.  The new problem created was that `restaurant_info` was filled with repeated `Restaurant` objects.  This was easily fixed by adding `DISTINCT` to my select method (the string called `atts`).  Thanks for all the help everyone.